# Differencing weekend fluctuations with R?

Tags: r, time-series, integral

Suppose a time-serie like this on the left-top corner with weekend and daily fluctuations. This time-series need differencing due to the rising ACF (bottom-left) and portmanteau tests' p -values too small, the weekend must be differenced away. Now I want to differentiate away the weekend-fluctuation in R, how to do that? This puzzle is from the lab [here](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-2.3132/tyo_2) (sorry not in English), data [here](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-2.3132/materiaali/Mat-2_3132_tyo_2__sahko.csv).

[image: aika/vrk = time/day, kulutus=consumption,]

*(translation: aika/vrk = time/day, kulutus=consumption)*

> **My ideas (silent discussion [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3606067#3606067)):**
>
> A) Friday-Monday -average for the weekend fluctuating values
>
> B)
>   create some sort of PID -controller and differentiate with that info
>
> C) ?
>
> **Possible tools in R**
>
> 1. `nls()`-`lm()`-`diff()` -problem?
> 2. `diffinv()`?
>
> **Some References**
>
> 1. Load Forecasting -paper by Eugene A. Feinberg: www.almozg.narod.ru/bible/lf.pdf

Comment: This is a typical load forecasting problem.   The seasonal terms are hour-of-the-day, day-of-the-week, week-of-the-year, holidays, economic activity, temperature, etc.  Notice the general rise in load in the top/left graph as temperature droops in the top/right graph.  Do a Google search for "forecasting electrical loads" and you'll get all sorts of information.  Also, search this site for other answers on electrical or power modeling/forecasting.

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

This is a typical load forecasting problem. The seasonal terms are hour-of-the-day, day-of-the-week, week-of-the-year, holidays, economic activity, temperature, etc. Notice the general rise in load in the top/left graph as temperature droops in the top/right graph. Do a Google search for "forecasting electrical loads" and you'll get all sorts of information. Also, search this site for other answers on electrical or power modeling/forecasting. – bill_080